# Leaflet opacity slider with L.tileLayer.wms

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.wms

I would like to control the opacity of a wms layer (using `L.tileLayer.wms`) in Leaflet using an opacity slider.

In `L.tileLayer.wms` I can control the opacity by setting the opacity:value.

This is my piece of code; The wms layer

```
var wmsLayer_2 = L.tileLayer.wms('https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php', {
  layers: ['CP.CadastralParcel'],
  crs: crs_6706,
    format: 'image/png',
  maxZoom: 21,
  transparent: true,
}).addTo(map);
```

The slider implemented in the leaflet control

```
function updateOpacity(value) {
        wmsLayer_2.setParams({opacity:value});
        };

var control = L.control.layers(baseMaps,
    {'Opacity_layer <br><input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" class="slider" onchange="updateOpacity(this.value)">':wmsLayer_2},{collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
```

However I can't manage the opacity.

[Here a complete example](https://jsfiddle.net/ludovico85/rsacz38x/44/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the Leaflet `opacity` **option** with a `opacity` **WMS parameter**.

When instantiating a `L.TileLayer.WMS`, any options that are not known to Leaflet are treated as WMS parameters, as explained in the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tilelayer-wms):

> If any custom options not documented here are used, they will be sent to the WMS server as extra parameters in each request URL. This can be useful for non-standard vendor WMS parameters.

This can be confusing, since the both options and WMS parameters are mixed together when instantiating.

However, [the `setParams()` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tilelayer-wms-setparams) works only on WMS parameters, *not* on options. So when instantiating, `opacity` is treated as a Leaflet option, but when passed to `setParams`, it's treated as a WMS parameter (and, in fact, in your example there's a `&opacity=` parameter appended to the URL of any WMS tile requests made by the browser).

tl;dr: use [the `setOpacity()` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#gridlayer-setopacity) instead.

Answer (score 2):

In your `updateOpacity` function you should use layer's `setOpacity` method:

```
function updateOpacity(value) {
  wmsLayer_2.setOpacity(value);
};
```

Comment: Answer from @IvanSanchez should be accepted since it's more complete with explanation. My answer was published about 5 minutes before his, otherwise I wouldn't publish it at all.